# How to use Twitter Kit Individual Share option in iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter

need favour in twitter code

hello,

i need a little favour if any buddy have working twitter code then please share... i waste 3 days for that but nothing going good .. following are the thing i research and implement too much [/I]

1- Sharekit :
        I use share kit but my current scenario is that i have custom facebook app and custom twitter ... facebook are implement and running ok ... not use sharekit api for facebook.

but i try the twitter source in share but it has too much hard to understand because they have manages all the objects in the items list in UIActionSheet.. and i only want to use twitter code and when i do to seperate its goona crazy..

2- MGTwitterEngine:
            I also try this but the code is not working after OAuth authentication its crashes the app .. and not tweet the string.

Note:
I care the text length i only tweet 20 characters ..

Outcome What I Request:
I want a twitter code which is simply implements and also have simple to integrate.. I only tweet ... please give me simple code and i am very thankful if you give me here and tell me how its work .. because i am too much exhaust..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i try the twitter source in share but it has too much hard to understand because they have manages all the objects in the items list in UIActionSheet.. and i only want to use twitter code and when i do to seperate its goona crazy..

If you check [the documentation](http://getsharekit.com/docs/#specific-service) for ShareKit, you will see that it is trivial to share with a specific service instead of triggering the action sheet.

Comment: i could not find the good help please refer me some if you could find and get then please give me because in actionSheet its looking wiered they have done very tricky code.. please help me.. !!